# How to stretch and reduce background image for text label using css

Tags: html, css, eclipse

I am designing a webpage that contains a background image
like arrow for label. I have designed the image in Photoshop.
My problem is that the image size is not expanding and reducing as
per text.
So please help me, what should I do? Is there any method to do this?

HTML:

```
        <label><span>First Name</span></label>
```

CSS:

```
        label
        {
        background-image:url('./images/lblimg.png');
        width:auto;
        display:inline-block;
        }


    span
         {
            line-height:50px;text-align:center;
         }
```

Comment: can you create a demo?

Comment: You may want to look at `background-size:100% 100%` or `background-size:cover`

Comment: No sir eclipse europa doesn't support css3.

Comment: do you need something like this http://jsfiddle.net/ga1ew5sp/?

Comment: thanks for answer,so how can i add css3 in eclipse europa.

Comment: Eclipse Europa is an IDE, it has nothing to do with CSS3 working or not. You may not be able to see it perfectly on Eclipse, but what matters is the user's browser and not the IDE.

Comment: That I don't know because I'm a designer not developer :) Change your question appropriately like what exactly you can use / want. specify which version of css / html you can use. So that experts from that area can help you better

Answer (score 0):

Use the style:

```
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

With `background-size:cover` the image will grow as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by it.

Comment: I don't think you need `background-repeat` in this case

Comment: hi, this property is with only css3 ,but i am using css2.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the `background-size` property to `100%` for both `with` and `height`.

```css
.bgimg{
    background-image: url(https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/defaulticon/icons/png/256x256/arrow-right.png);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<span class="bgimg">
    div with little text :) 
</span>
<br />
<span class="bgimg">
    div with more and more and more text :) 
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, both using CSS3 `background-size`:

1. Use `background-size: cover`: the background image will grow as large as possible until it covers the whole background area.

   - Pros:

     - The image will cover the whole area
     - The image will not be stretched
   - Cons:

     - As the image doesn't stretch, just grows until it covers the whole area, some parts of the picture may not be displayed.
2. Use `background-size: 100% 100%`: the background image will occupy 100% of the width and height of the container.

   - Pros:

     - The image will cover the whole area
     - The whole image will be displayed (no hidden parts)
   - Cons:

     - The image may be stretched (although this could be considered a pro, specially for the behavior expected in the question)

In your particular case, the second option will be better as you want to display the whole arrow without risking some parts getting hidden.

In your code, it would look like this:

```
label
{
     background-image:url('./images/lblimg.png');
     background-size:100% 100%;
     width:auto;
     display:inline-block;
}
```

---

Edit (as per CSS2 request by OP): **This cannot be achieved exclusively with CSS2 unless you change the HTML code**. In that case you would actually not be using a background-image, but directly an image that would be behind the text.

This is how the HTML would look:

```
<label>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals/" alt="Random pic" />
    <span>First Name</span>
</label>
```

This is how the CSS would look:

```
label {
    width:auto;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}

span {
    line-height:50px;text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}

img {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

You can see an example of the CSS3 and CSS2 solutions on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/othnjk5x/

Comment: but what about usingcss2. eclipse Europa version support only css2 not css3

Comment: What do you mean by "eclipse Europa version support only css2 not css3"? Because that has me confused. Is it that the IDE doesn't display it correctly in the preview tab? That eclipse does not recognize it as a valid rule and shows a warning? What should matter is the end result in a browser/phone, and not what the IDE shows/says

Comment: I mean eclipse europa support  only css2 .this 'size' property doesn't comes in css2. iam using above css code for background image,but what i want is image should be expand or reduce as per text give for label.i want all image prat should be shown without hiding or repeating image .

Comment: But again, as I told you before: Eclipse Europa is an IDE, it doesn't matter what it supports; what really matters is what the browser that will run the CSS supports, as that will be the real visualization. Unless you have old-browser support requirements, [the CSS3 solution is the way to go as it is supported by over 93% of the browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size)

Comment: thanks for help,i got it .it works in latest browsers

Comment: Great. Good luck with the project

Comment: it works fine ,but i want to align text in center.how should i do?

Comment: Add a `display: inline-block` to the `span` and that should do it

Comment: but the problem is ,it is an arrow like image.Its background in Photoshop is white rectangle so i want only arrow not white background.because of this only text is not in center.so how can i do this in Photoshop.waiting for your valuable answer.thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, and I'm not sure I'll be able to help you if it's an issue with Photoshop

Comment: yes its an issue with photoshop.so where i can find the solution to this problem.

Comment: Stack Overflow is only for programming questions; for Photoshop, you may want to visit the [Graphic Design stack exchange site](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).